# Correct punctuation to define a person's position

Tags: meaning, punctuation

If I have a list of people in, for example, a business, are there any style guidelines for defining their position? E.g.:

- John Smith --- Director
- Mary Higgins --- Chairwoman

My instinct is to use an em dash (indicated by the triple dashes above). I haven't found anything in the Chicago Manual of Style on this topic.

Comment: It's very common to use a simple comma in place of the dash or dashes you indicate. But I've seen the punctuation handled in a number of different ways in this type of Name|Job Title presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd use parentheses:

John Smith (Director)
Mary Higgins (Chairwoman)

This seems to me to be fairly neat and scans well.  The parentheses also allows you to insert extra information if you'd like to without grammatically affecting any following text:

John Smith (Director of Social Services, South-West Division)

Comment: Thanks, the parentheses do appear to be very practical here.